# Julia crashes with Queryverse any time there is a typo in the variable name

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia (from R). Using V1.7.1 in VScode notebooks. The following code crashes Julia and requires a restart, rather than just reporting and error:

```
using Queryverse
using DataFramesMeta
df = DataFrame(Name = ["Jon","Adam","Harry"],
               Age = [42,40,41] )
df |> @filter(_.age > 40)
```

The error is that 'age' in the filter command should be Age. However, it's common to make these mistakes, and I don't want to have to restart every time I do. Is there a workaround, or is this to do with VScode?

Comment: I can reproduce this on the latest version of all packages, VSCode, and the Julia extension. It appears to be a bug in the Julia extension notebook support (this works in the REPL, VSCode, as well as VSCode notebooks with an IJulia rather than the inbuilt Julia extension kernel)

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been having a number of problems with VSCode that has almost made me give up on Julia. I might switch to Juno.

Comment: FWIW I've used Juno since 2013 (back when it was built on LightTable!) and put off moving to VSCode for a long time, but by now I find it works pretty well and is quite robust. The native notebook support is pretty new (MS only introduced it last summer) and can be rough around the edges still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing this appears to be a bug in the (relatively new) native Jupyter support of the Julia VSCode extension.

I've filed an issue [here](https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode/issues/2682) and will update this answer if the problem gets resolved.